# How to show a Splash screen untill InAppWebView loads completely

Tags: flutter

I don't got an idea that how to show a splash screen until the InAppWebView loads the page completely. Kindly look at the code and give me a solution.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';
import './config.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  InAppWebViewController _webViewController;
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;
  DateTime currentBackPressTime;

  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    if (_webViewController != null) {
      _webViewController.goBack();
    }

    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
        now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
      currentBackPressTime = now;
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Tap back again to leave");
      return Future.value(false);
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  }

  Future<void> _onShare(BuildContext context) async {
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();

    await Share.share(url,
        sharePositionOrigin: box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            AppBarTitle,
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(AppBarTitleColor)),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color(AppBarColor),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.share,
                  color: Color(AppBarShareIconColor),
                ),
                onPressed: () => _onShare(context),
              ),
            )
          ],
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0.0),
            child: LinearProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3),
              valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
              value: progress,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: InAppWebView(
            initialUrl: Url,
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
              debuggingEnabled: true,
            )),
            onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
              _webViewController = controller;
              _webViewController.android.zoomIn();
              _webViewController.android.zoomOut();
            },
            onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
              setState(() {
                this.url = url;
              });
            },
            onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
              setState(() {
                this.url = url;
                progress = 0;
              });
            },
            onProgressChanged:
                (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
              setState(() {
                this.progress = progress / 100;
              });
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried some methods like adding over widget in stack and removes it conditionally but that too is not achieving properly.

I've been looking for the solution but I didn't got yet! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: means inshort you want to show loader until splash screen loads

Comment: nope! I want to show splash screen until the webview loads completely

Comment: I did this already but I show loader until InAppWebview  loads

Comment: I found solution bro.... As I said I don't want to show loader ,I want to show Splash Screen